# Take the versions other than Max SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a Table with 4 columns.
I want to retrieve the highest version for the combination of Number,Code and Serial No.
If there are multiple versions the remaining versions I need another result set.

```
Number  Version Code    Serial No
12345   1        VB      88
12345   2        VB      88
23456   1        VB      44
33334   1        VB      55
33334   2        VB      55
33334   3        VB      55
```

In One table I need only highest issues for each Number,Code,Serial No. My result1

```
Number  Version Code    Serial No
12345   2        VB      88
23456   1        VB      44
33334   3        VB      55
```

Another result set

```
Number  Version Code    Serial No
12345   1        VB      88
33334   1        VB      55
33334   2        VB      55
```

Anyway I can get the first set using the query.
How can get the second set. Without using temp table.

Comment: [`EXCEPT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) or another way depending on your logic is to invert some of the filters.

Comment: what's the logic to create the 2nd result?

Answer (score 2):

TO get second result set, use something like below. Didn't get to run the query

```
select * from 
(select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by number,code,SerialNo order by version desc) as rnk
from table t) 
where rnk <> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `row_number` function to get both the results, changing the `where` condition.

```
select number,version,code,serialno
from (select t.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by number,code,serialno order by version desc) as rnum
      from tablename t
     ) x
where rnum > 1 --rnum=1 for the first result
```

Comment: I guess if we order by `version desc`, then highest version will get rank 1.

Comment: yes..that is what the op needs for the 2nd result..all rows except the highest version.

Comment: Ok I though other way around.

Answer (score 2):

**[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**:

change `cte.rn=1` to `cte.rn!=1` to get the second result set

```
with cte as (
  select   
      t.*
    , rn = row_number() over (
            partition by t.[Number], t.[Code], t.[Serial No]
            order by t.[Version] desc
            )
    from tbl t
)
select cte.*
  from cte
  where cte.rn = 1
```

---

**[top with ties](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)**:

```
select top 1 with ties
    t.*
  from tbl t
  order by row_number() over (
    partition by t.[Number], t.[Code], t.[Serial No] 
    order by t.[Version] desc)
```

second result set:

```
select t.*
from tbl t

except 

select top 1 with ties
    t.*
  from tbl t
  order by row_number() over (
    partition by t.[Number], t.[Code], t.[Serial No] 
    order by t.[Version] desc)
```

---

inner join on `max(version)`:

change `m.[Version] = t.[Version]` to `m.[Version] != t.[Version]` to get the second result set

```
select t.* 
  from tbl t
    inner join (
      select m.[Number], m.[Code], m.[Serial No], Version = max(m.[Version])
      from tbl m
      group by m.[Number], m.[Code], m.[Serial No]
      ) 
      on m.[Number] =  t.[Number]
        and m.[Code] =  t.[Code]
        and m.[Serial No] = t.[Serial No]
        and m.[Version] = t.[Version]
```

---

**[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with `max([Version])` **[over()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)** version:

change `m.[Version] = t.[Version]` to `m.[Version] != t.[Version]` to get the second result set

```
with cte as (
  select 
       t.*
    , MaxVersion = max([Version]) over (
            partition by t.[Number], t.[Code], t.[Serial No]
            )
    from tbl t
)
select cte.[Number], cte.[Code], cte.[Serial No], cte.[Version]
  from cte
  where cte.MaxVersion = cte.[Version]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the query to get MAX(VERSION) already, it is logical to use it as a subquery.

MAX(VERSION):

```
SELECT NUMBER,CODE,SERIAL,MAX(VERSION) 
    FROM Q
    GROUP BY NUMBER,CODE,SERIAL
```

The rest:

```
SELECT NUMBER,CODE,SERIAL,VERSION 
    FROM Q
    WHERE (NUMBER,CODE,SERIAL,VERSION) NOT IN (
        SELECT NUMBER,CODE,SERIAL,MAX(VERSION) 
            FROM Q
            GROUP BY NUMBER,CODE,SERIAL 
    )
```